# Constraints in DocCplex on Python don't work

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem, but when I insert this constraint it doesn't work:
'''

```
mdl.add_constraints(isinstance(w[i]/5, int) == True for i in range(0,5))
```

'''
where w is defined as follow :
'''

```
w = mdl.integer_var_list(5,5,30, 'W')
```

'''
Python generates this error :

> Expecting sequence of constraints, got: False at position 0

I tried also to insert the constraint differently :

```
mdl.add_constraints(w[i]%5 == 0 for i in range(0,5))
```

But I get this error :

> unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Var' and 'int'

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Since modulo is not linear you need to turn that to a linear constraint as in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoomodulo.py

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

# and suppose we need to order quantities
# that should be 3 multipliers

nbbus40div3 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40div3')
nbbus30div3 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30div3')

mdl.add(nbbus40==3*nbbus40div3)
mdl.add(nbbus30==3*nbbus30div3)

mdl.solve()


for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex for your answer!

Also, I can't express the objective function, this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
def portfolio_return( weights, returns):
    return weights.T @ returns

def portfolio_vol( weights, covmatrix):
    return np.sqrt(weights.T @ covmatrix @ weights)

def sharp_ratio(er,covmat,w,rf = 0.01):
    r_p = portfolio_return(w, er)/100
    sigma_p = portfolio_vol(w,cov)/100
    return (r_p-rf)/sigma_p

mdl.minimize(-sharp_ratio(quartered_er, cov,np.array(w)))
```

The error is :

> loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type QuadExpr which has
> no callable sqrt method

Thanks again Alex!